# Doctrine/Symfony2: Saving data with batch is getting slower and slower

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Class "Offers".
Offers has a City, City has a Region and Region has a Country. These have all foreign Keys.
I get my offer in a foreach and I save it to the database:

```
foreach ($catalogs as $catalog)

$offers = $catalog->getOffers();

    foreach ($offers as $offer) {
    $counter++;
    $this->DatabaseWriter->create($offer);


                if($counter > 100) {
                    try {
                        $this->DatabaseWriter->flush();
                        $this->DatabaseWriter->clear('MyBundle\Entity\Offer');
                        $counter = 0;
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        echo "----->".$e->getMessage()."<-----";
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

I have a batch with size 100. After the 100 I make a flush. The first 1000 are going really fast, but the nect catalog with about 1000 offers is getting slwoer and slower at about 2000 offers.
I treif to make a `clear` but this is not possible because of the relationships from the offer to the catalog, city, region and country.
Is there a way to make ist faster so that the memory isn't getting fuller and fuller?
THANKS FOR ANY HELP!

Comment: Yes: Don't use doctrine. They say so themselves: _"An ORM tool is not primarily well-suited for mass inserts, updates or deletions. [...] we recommend you use the tools for your particular RDBMS for these bulk operations."_ cf [batch-processing docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html)

Comment: That is useful advise, but I use doctrine in batches to fire Subscribers and listeners. How would I proceed with this in mind?